# Word Choice: Colloquial or idiomatic expression for being in denial about being proved wrong

Tags: idiom-requests, translation

I am looking for a colloquial expression that denotes someone's behavior when they disregard the fact that they have lost an argument or that one has found a flaw in their logic or that they are plain wrong, and go on to present weak repostes to save face such as to blame the problem on outside influences or circumstances. I need a colloquialism because I guess in formal language you could say 'someone does something in bad faith' when they are being disingenuous or dishonest. I can think of 'grasping at straws'. Eg: John, stop grasping at straws, we know it wasn't the dog that knocked over the vase. 
Maybe there isn't one expression to cover all scenarios; just in case, as further aid the French might say someone is 'de mauvaise foi'. But it is said jokingly and not accusingly, to mean 'it's only too obvious what you're doing, just give up already!'

Comment: 'When in a hole, stop digging' is used, but is not specific to the situation you describe (and has been given on ELU before).

Comment: Do you want an expression to describe the behavior, or something you can say *to* someone behaving that way? Because your description of the French phrase comes very close to the latter. It's idiomatic to say "Give *it* up already!" to someone who persists in the face of facts, logic, and/or common sense.

Comment: "[You're living in your own private Idaho](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yXmnmvDl-ao)."

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I like that, I think that exactly captures what I want to say

Comment: If they are not doing it to save face, they may have a psychological condition, *cognitive dissonance*---MW gives *psychological conflict resulting from incongruous beliefs and attitudes held simultaneously.*

Answer (score 1):

*John, **is arguing on - refusing to throw in the towel, but** we know it wasn't the dog that knocked over the vase.*

> **Throw in the towel**
>   - Give up, to avoid further punishment when facing certain defeat.
>   - http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/throw-in-the-towel.html

Comment: This doesn't describe "being in denial about being proved wrong".

Comment: @Laurel I think refusing to throw in the metaphorical towel, implies the protagonist thinks he can still win the fight or argument or whatever. If someone says he should throw it in, that someone is implying that  the protagonist has no chance of winning.

Comment: I think the phrase "refusing to throw in the towel" fits better.

Comment: @Laurel agreed, so I've re-worked example sentence now.

Answer (score 0):

One in this situation may be said to *refuse to* [*desert*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/desert+a+sinking+ship) or [*abandon*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/abandon+ship) *a sinking ship*, or perhaps simply *refuse to* *abandon ship*.

> "John, *stop refusing to abandon ship*. We know it wasn't the dog that
>   knocked over the vase.

If you agree with @EdwinAshworth's comment, I won't *dig in my heels*.

From *The Free Dictionary*:

> [dig in (one's)
>   heels](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/dig+heels+in): to refuse to
>   alter one's course of action or opinions; to be obstinate or
>   determined / to refuse to do what other people are trying to persuade
>   you to do, especially to refuse to change your opinions or plans

When John *refuses to abandon his sinking ship*, you could say:

> "John, *quit digging in your heels*. We know it wasn't the dog that
>   knocked over the vase.

Comment: I don't consider the metaphor stretches that far while retaining idiomaticity.

Answer (score 0):

In British English, you could say

> John, face it, we know it wasn't the dog that knocked over the vase.

It means 'face up to the truth'.

Answer (score 0):

Persist in error. This is part of the quote [to err is human...](https://www.reddit.com/r/quotes/comments/36ub5q/to_err_is_human_but_to_persist_in_error_out_of/) which goes back to Roman times, if not ancient Greek. Perhaps not all that common on the street but still accurate.

Answer (score -1):

"Joe Bloggs is **living in cloud cuckoo land.** He just won't see reason and keeps boasting to his classmates that his professor will turn a blind eye to his flagrant plagiarism".

**Living in cloud cuckoo land:**  To think that things are completely impossible, rather than understanding how things really are. (Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: I think means the person is characteristically delusional, whereas here I mean maybe a one-off behaviour

Comment: @Arun  There is no reason why "living in cloud cuckoo land" cannot be used to cover a one-off situation and, furthermore, the expression does not express or imply any clinical delusional trait or characteristic on the part of the person concerned. I think you maybe conflating your understanding of my answer with a description of someone as being "cuckoo" per se which Merriam-Webster Dictionary informs us is "a silly or crackbrained person", in other words quite possibly chronically delusional.

Comment: @Arun  "Crackbrained": Merriam-Webster gives us as an example the following sentence-in-context: "Once a brilliant dancer, he died a crackbrain in a mental institution". I do not think the usage of "crackbrain" in this context has any connection with a crack-cocaine user.